# Why did my physics start working up after adding a face mask?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I am making a ninja, I added a hoodie and put a cloth modifier on it.  I put a collision modifier on the body and everything was working great.  I moved on to the next step and made a face mask, put the cloth modifier on it to, and now I am having problems.  The face mask wants to fall through the body even though it has a collision modifier on it.  It also goes through the hoodie. The hoodie has also started acting up, as in the ends of the sleeves want to get all twisted and spiky when I start the simulation. I have pinned the hoodie and the mask.[image]

Comment: Ensure the objects are all on the same layer.

Comment: I just checked and everything is on the same layer except the custom shapes I made for the bones.

Comment: It depends, usually caused by intersection. If it doesn't, you really need to upload your problematic file here to get first aid quickly. You can use http://www.pasteall.org/blend.

Comment: @LeonCheung The preferred upload site is now Blend-exchange, see: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297/can-we-have-a-service-for-uploading-blendfiles/629#629

Comment: blend-exchange .com .org .somethingelse?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I had a week off, so this comment is a little delayed, but I think I figured it out.  I changed the outer and inner of the body, and the distance and repel of the cloth along with a bunch of other tweaks and that fixed most the problem, then I fixed a couple areas where the clothes where to close and that fixed more of the problem.  still having miner issues, but I think I'm on the right track.